Shortcodes not evaluate when using in a saved patter block
I have the following set-up on my Wordpress:

Have a set of shortcodes (SC) which call a weather API to display various sets of weather data
The SC uses the custom field 'postcode' set at page level to know which location to use
Created a Gutenberg pattern block; which uses these SCs to design a widget displaying the data

Expected behaviour:
The exception was that in every page where the pattern is used, the shortcodes would be re-evaluated when the user views the page, pulling the latest weather data for the location associated with the page.
Actual behaviour:
The pages all display the same data. From the caching system which I use to store the API weather data, I can see that the shortcodes are not being re-evaluated whenever the pages are viewed (perhaps only when the patter is edited? Or when the page in which the pattern is used is saved?)
My question
Is this normal behaviour? I would not expect Wordpress to save the content which is generated by the shortcode; but rather re-execute it on every pageview. How could I achieve my expected design? i.e having the ability to change the layout of a single pattern, to achieve the changes on every page where the patter is used.
Thanks all!
